# pecl oauth - problem with request engine

Tags: php, oauth, pecl, pecl-oauth

I am trying to use pecl oauth

```
$oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
```

but when a call to

```
$oauth->setRequestEngine(OAUTH_REQENGINE_CURL)
```

i am getting a warning that constant OAUTH_REQENGINE_CURL is a string and NOT an int.

The other constant used to set the engine OAUTH_REQENGINE_CURL is an integer.

Is this a bug? Have i missed something?

Using php 5.3.5 and pecl-oauth v1.2

OAUTH_REQENGINE_CURL is not defined as a constant.

Although in file php_auth.c the following lines define the 2 engines

define OAUTH_REQENGINE_STREAMS 1

define OAUTH_REQENGINE_CURL 2

Thanks,

Comment: First of all, post the warning message. I assume that `OAUTH_REQENGINE_CURL` is not defined as constant. Check the API documentation of the library if you're using the correct one. If that does not help, check the source code for `define` or `const` statements.

Comment: Where did you get the oauth build from perhaps it didn't have `libcurl` as an option

Comment: thanks Glass Robot. That was the problem.